# WooCommerce Custom User Access

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, author

I'm making a website that is a book author ecommerce website.

I would like a method for authors to login and be able to only see their own product and anything assigned to his user. I've been able to assign individual products to individual users but if they login they can see other authors books(products) and information which i do not want and they have shop manager all access which is not my goal.

If possible, would there be a way for a author to login through the front end and stay there and see all the product information there, reports etc which would usually be in /WP-admin.

Update: I've realized you can make a product private and then edit the user roles to be able to see this or not using the User Role Plugin. This is fantastic and what I wanted. However this does not apply to WooCommerce Reports which shows reports of everything thus far. any ideas?

Comment: I'd probably add some custom sections to the My Account page and redirect author logins to the front-end. This is probably more complex that will get answered here.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with having custom User Roles, and assigning or limiting capabilities of each role, using this handy plugin: 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/

See this screenshots page for easy understanding of this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/screenshots/

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful and gets me further towards my goal. I'm unable to find a way for a custom user to only  be able to view woocommerce products created by them, so they can't see info about others thus far though.